# Microsoft Edge .WebView2 folder, visibility and permissions

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am having issues with Autodesk's DWG TrueView 2023, which shows a `Microsoft Edge can't read and write to data folder: C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2023 - English\.WebView2\1\EBWebView` at launch. When logged in as a local admin, or if I give all users `full control` permissions on the `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\DWG TrueView 2023 - English` I have no issues, but of course that's a horrible solution. What I was hoping to do is just loosen security on the Edge data folder, but even with hidden files and folders showing, I don't see the folder in question. I don't see the `.WebView2` or anything deeper, so I wonder, is the folder naming there something special? Or is it possible to have a folder hidden in a way that even `Show Hidden Files and Folders` doesn't expose it? [This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder) suggests that a `.WebView2` folder in the Program Files folder makes sense, and also suggests that Autodesk didn't read this document that says with regards to Win32 platform

> On this platform, in most cases, you should specify a custom UDF
> location, rather than using the default UDF location. This ensures
> that the WebView2 control has Write access so that the WebView2
> control is able to create the UDF and then write to it.

But it doesn't seem to explain hiding the folder. So, my question is, is there some way to "really hide" a folder, and if so can I still expose it? I am tempted to just create the `.WebView2` folder and give authenticated users access, but I want to have a better understanding of what is happening before I test that.

Yes, this is just reason 956 why Autodesk are utter morons, but life as an architect is working around their incompetence. I despise MS Edge too, especially Microsoft's douchbag forcing the icon on the desktop and the task bar, but that's just reason 987 why my daily driver is a Mac. ;)